# in mongodb collection find data using three parameters month year and employeeId

Tags: mongodb

This is my Data :
find data object and return using three parameters Month Year and employeeId.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f7217b7e72a11307321a301"),
    "employeeId" : "2707",
    "employeeName" : "gowdham",
    "status" : "Present",
    "date" : ISODate("2020-09-23T00:00:00Z"),
    "clientName" : "dcdcdc",
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f721b2de72a11307321a302"),
    "employeeId" : "2707",
    "employeeName" : "gowdham",
    "status" : "Present",
    "date" : ISODate("2020-09-28T00:00:00Z"),
    "clientName" : "Lorent",
    
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f72244be72a11307321a310"),
    "employeeId" : "2708",
    "employeeName" : "HrJosh",
    "status" : "Present",
    "date" : ISODate("2019-08-23T00:00:00Z"),
    "clientName" : "Lorent",
    
}
```

I need to find all 2019-08 duration and employeeId "2707" datas:

```
db.collection.find({
  "$expr": {
    "$and": [
      {"$eq": [{ "$year": "$date" }, 2019]},
      {"$eq": [{ "$month": "$date" }, 09]},
      {"$eq": { "$employeeId": "2707" }}

    ]
  }
});
```

this correct or not ? i'm getting error... plz give anyone solution for this

expecting output is:

```
   {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f7217b7e72a11307321a301"),
    "employeeId" : "2707",
    "employeeName" : "gowdham",
    "status" : "Present",
    "date" : ISODate("2020-09-23T00:00:00Z"),
    "clientName" : "dcdcdc",
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f721b2de72a11307321a302"),
    "employeeId" : "2707",
    "employeeName" : "gowdham",
    "status" : "Present",``
    "date" : ISODate("2020-09-28T00:00:00Z"),
    "clientName" : "Lorent",
    
}
```

Comment: wrong syntax in last match for employeeId, you can do this way `{ $eq: ["$employeeId", "2707"] }`  or you can use this way also [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qwaaz_F2k9M)

Comment: how to implement this to node js